# Add user to Fan page after website registration using Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

As we all know we can use Facebook to simplify registration and sign-in process to our website.

My question is, is it possible to automatically make a user a fan of a Fan page after he uses the Facebook registration/sign-in at our website?

Comment: So you basically want to highjack each login (that uses Facebook Connect) and transform it into a Like for the respective page, right?

Comment: No. What I want is if they choose to register at our website using FB, they should automatically be a fan of our fan page.

Comment: Interesting question but I see a problem in the fact that can be heavily abused to acquire likes.

Comment: There is one way that you can kind of do this - check out www.fansflood.com - the way I see it working for you is they log in using facebook to your page then you can use the fansflood script to not only show a LIKE button which can have them liking your facebook fan page (not necessarily the page they're on) but after LIKING the fansflood script reveals some form of reward that you can set up - eg: a link to some paid content you want to give for free, a free download, video or discount etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, the user must be able to manually "fan" your page. No programming methods are allowed. The most you can do is redirect the user to your page after registration.